# Passing React button text value around

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have this code:

```
<button id="gnrl"  onClick={() => this.selectChannel()}>General</button>
```

How can I pass the text `General` around as a parameter? I.e. grep all the text between the 2 button tags?

I have a function that does this:

```
  selectChannel = (channelValue) => {
    var x = document.getElementById("general").value;
    this.setState({ channelValue: x })
  }
```

But I don't want to get the value as that has to be a hardcoded property. I would like to be able to change `General` to anything else e.g. `Random` and that would be the value passed around. any ideas?

Comment: Really hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is a good start. You should keep the text inside a `state` or a `prop`.

Comment: @KrzysztofDąbrowski really? I just want to click on a button and have the value of that button available to me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's something you want to achieve but you can create component that will render `<button>` with whatever text passed as props.

Component:

```
<ButtonComponent text="General" />
```

Component's definition:

```
const ButtonComponent = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(props.text);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={ handleClick }>{ props.text }</button>
  );
};
```

**UPDATE (same component in class notation):**

```
export default class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log(this.props.text);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>
                { this.props.text }
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I pass in props if I have set mine up like: `export default class Button extends React.Component {`

Comment: You can simply refer to `this.props`. I've updated my comment with different way o defining the same component.

Answer (score 12):

You can do using target

```
selectChannel = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
}

<button onClick={(e) => this.selectChannel(e)}>General</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you hardcode that as a variable and pass the variable?

```
render () {
  var buttonText = "General";
  return (
    <button id="gnrl"  onClick={() => this.selectChannel(buttonText)}>{buttonText}</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I want nothing hardcoded because I want to use any value

Comment: You can set the value of buttonText to that any value whenever it is available.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onClick={e => alert(e.target.innerText)}>General</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have enough information, but here I go: I think you should keep the text in the state of the component if it is defined in that component.

If the text can be somehow generated in an ancestor component, you should define it in the state of such component and pass it as a prop to the component containing the button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good or bad practice, but it can be done with: `e.target.firstChild.data` or `e.target.lastChild.data`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button text via props to component.

`<Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onClick} >Buttonone</Button>`

`<button className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}> {props.children} </button>`

Like this you can get Button InnerHtml value to component